# How to rescale the axes on a 3D graph?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I currently have a graph in which the x and y axes take values on the order of 10^-4. Which looks messy,

```
Plot3D[F[r, y], {r, -10^-4, 10^-4}, {y, -1.5 10^-4, 10^-4}, PlotRange -> All , AxesLabel -> {Text[Style["r (m)", Italic, 14]], Text[Style["y (m)", Italic, 14]], Text[Style["F (TN)", Italic, 14]]}]
```

[image]

Unfortunately just scaling the argument of the function and consequently the range in Plot3D produces weird results,

```
Plot3D[F[r/10^6, y/10^6], {r, -100, 100}, {y, -150, 100}, PlotRange -> All , AxesLabel -> {Text[Style["r (μm)", Italic, 14]], Text[Style["y (μm)", Italic, 14]], Text[Style["F (TN)", Italic, 14]]}]
```

[image]

As you can see they're not the same graph with the second one being rather poor quality. Is there a better way to rescale the axis?

Comment: Can you provide the definition of `F` for testing purposes.

Comment: You could improve the quality of the scaled plot increasing the number of [`PlotPoints`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotPoints.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the unscaled function and just scale the ticks (see [`Ticks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html?q=Ticks) for details):

```
ticks1 = Table[{n, n*10^6}, {n, -10^-4, 10^-4, 1/2 10^-4}];
Plot3D[F[r, y], {r, -10^-4, 10^-4}, {y, -1.5 10^-4, 10^-4}, PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> {Text[Style["r (m)", Italic, 14]], Text[Style["y (m)", Italic, 14]], 
  Text[Style["F (TN)", Italic, 14]]}, Ticks -> {ticks1, ticks1, Automatic}]
```